# Is there a way to unhide or edit the footer in Squarespace when the "hide footer" code was (accidentally) put into the footer?

Tags: header, footer, display, squarespace

It had been a while since I built a new site in Squarespace, and I accidentally pasted the following code INTO the footer of my site on Squarespace using a code block (instead of the code injection panel...like a dummy):

it was either:

```
<style>
  .header{
    display:none !important;
  }
 #footer-sections{
  Display:none !important;
  }
</style>
```

OR:

```
<style>
  .header, #footer-sections{
    display:none !important;
  }
</style>
```

Now, I can't edit those sections to remove it so my shopping cart is inaccessible. I've added a shopping cart where I can manually, but it still doesn't always appear and is not as functional.

Help!

I've tried adding override code into my custom CSS and Code Injection using "!important",
but unfortunately I think the original code also already contained "!important"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is only for _programming_ questions. You might have better luck on [webmasters.se] (but please read their help documents to make sure before posting_.

Answer (score 0):

While editing your website and actively viewing/editing a page which you know to have the footer code within it, [open your browser's developer tools/inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools).

> Keyboard:
>
> - Windows: Ctrl + Shift + I or F12
> - macOS: ⌘ + ⌥ + I

You can then use the inspector to find an area near the bottom of the page, close to the hidden element in question. Having done that, browser the underlying code to find the hidden element on the page. Once found, click on that element within the inspector and then disable the applicable CSS rules which are hiding that element. With the element showing, you should then be able to hover over the block field as usually, select "Edit" and proceed to edit/delete the code (or remove the block entirely).

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4x0KXvmMycM) that gives a visual example of using your developer tools and inspector while in the backend editing system within Squarespace. However, the purpose of the video is different than your purpose, so it does not demonstrate every step outlined above; it simply shows an example of opening and using dev-tools/inpsector.

If that doesn't work, you can temporarily add the following via [Footer Code Injection](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815908-Using-code-injection#footer):

```
<style>
body #footer-sections {
  display: block !important;
}
</style>
```

By adding more specificity with `body`, it should override the CSS you added already, showing the footer sections and allowing you to go in and remove that code block.

Comment: I appreciate the help, unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any of the code using the inspector...

Comment: @MathewPatalano: Please update your question to include the code itself, that is, the code you call the "hide header footer - always" code. Also, when you say that you pasted the code "into the footer", could you clarify whether you pasted it into "footer code injection" or whether you pasted it into a code block within the footer of your site?

Comment: the site is www.cararomero.com and I believe I stuck this code into the footer on the home page (via a code block - see revised question above with details)

Comment: I am sure this can be remedied, @MathewPatalano. And, providing a link to the site will be quite helpful to providing the answer. However, the site/page in question has a password set and so therefore cannot be viewed. If you would like to post that view-only password, I will take a look. If you do not want to expose your password, you may set a different password temporarily, then set it back to the one you have now once your question is answered.

Comment: Hello Brandon, thank you so much - the password is CR2023
Please let me know if there's anything else I can tell you that could be helpful.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! That worked for the footer and I was able to delete the code. Turned out I had the code on multiple pages, so going through and removing it page by page is bringing the header back.

Can I send you a pie or something for your help??? :)

Comment: @MathewPatalano : Well, that's good to hear. Glad to help. Just make sure to correspondingly upvote my answer/comment and mark the answer accepted and that should be good.

Comment: @MathewPatalano : Would you mind accepting this answer as the correct one and upvoting as appropriate? Thank you.